# jquery form : select menu unable to display selected option

Tags: jquery, forms

I am working on a jQuery form that is used to submit data to a database.
The form is also editable, and I am unable to retrieve the selected value for an option from the database while editing.

In other words, I am not able to read the selected option from the database and mark it selected while displaying the form.

ve_type is the variable in which the selected value is stored while submitting the form.
ve_type is the variable in which the selected value while reading form the database.

This logic is working with input type text, but fails with select menu.

Any help is much appreciated.

```
<label for="vetype" class = "select"><strong>Vehicle Type:</strong></label>
<select name="vetype" id="vetype" value="$ve_type" />");
<option value="car">Car</option>
<option value="van">Van</option>
<option value="truck">Truck</option></select>
```

Comment: value="$ve_type" is it correct??? "$" <---- ??? look at manuals

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that there is no attribute value for select, you should try to add attribute selected on the option :

`$("#vetype option[value='yourSelectedValue']").attr('selected','selected');`